# red only RGB 24 bits c

Tags: c++, image, pixel, mbed

I'm working with the OV7670 camera, mbed and a laser using the following code

```
void CameraSnap(){
    led4 = 1;

            // Kick things off by capturing an image
    camera.CaptureNext();
    while(camera.CaptureDone() == false);     

    camera.ReadStart(); 

    t1 = t.read_ms();

    unsigned colorpixel;
    unsigned int byte1, byte2;
    int x;
    int y;

    int i = 0;


    for (int i=0; i < SIZEX; i++) {

        Maximo[i] = 0;
        PuntosMaximo[i] = 0;
}


    for(y = 0; y<SIZEY; y++)            
        for(x = 0; x<SIZEX; x++)      
        {  

 // Read in the first half of the image
        if(format == 'b')
            {
                camera.ReadOnebyte();
            }
        else
            if(format == 'y' || format == 'r')
                {
                    byte1 = camera.ReadOnebyte();
                    //pc.putc(byte1); 
                }    
                // Read in the Second half of the image

        byte2 = camera.ReadOnebyte();

        red = (byte1 & 0xF8)>>3; 
        green = (((byte1 << 8) | byte2) & 0x5E)>>5;
        blue = (byte2 & 0x1F);
        unsigned short data = (red+ green + blue) /3;
             pc.putc(data); 

         if ((red > Maximo[x] )&& (green < 10) && (blue < 10 )) {
            Maximo[x] = rojo;
            PuntosMaximo[x] = y;

         }

}  
camera.ReadStop();



t2 = t.read_ms();
```

I want the program to store the max intensity pixels in `Maximo[i]` from a RGB 24 bits image but in the OV7670 grabber (https://mbed.org/users/edodm85/code/OV7670_Test_Code/file/d0d4760d32b2/main.cpp) it only shows a black and white image.

Could you please give me some advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like a chunk of your code is missing, and the formatting is messed up ? And why the C tag ?

Comment: Im using the mbed platform and it is similar to c, the rest of the code corrects the distortion of the lens (it was converted from matlab so I know that it works)

Comment: Look at the line below `"Start reading in the image data ..."` and tell me if that is correct. Also the messed up formatting makes it hard to read - you should fix this to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: thanks for your tips, im new here :) I'll correct it ASAP